# Renaming a file with ItemAdded Event Receiver

Tags: development, visual-studio, event-receivers, splistitem

I am using an Event Receiver to rename a file in a document library. For some reason this doesn't seem to work.

```
public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An item was added.
    /// </summary>
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        properties.ListItem.File.CheckOut();
        properties.ListItem["Name"] = properties.ListItem["Name"].ToString().Replace(" ", "+");
        properties.ListItem.Update();
        properties.ListItem.File.CheckIn("file name has been changed");
    }

}
```

Sorry, how can I check CheckIn Comments within SharePoint. I want to see if "file name has been changed" is being ran.

Comment: I would do something like "var item = properties.ListItem;" first and work with that object from there on. Besides that the code looks fine to me, although I can't run it right know. Have you checked with SharePoint Manager if the EventReceiver is attached to the list you're working on?

Comment: It appears to be added. I see the name though is weird. The event receivers name is "EventReceiver1" in Visual Studio. The name in Powershell is returning "EventReceiver1ItemAdded"

Comment: I didn't do anything to FeatureActivating(). Could this be the issue?

Comment: When you add an event receiver you can choose a name, so that could totally be the name. If it is added, than you should be able to debug it using Visual Studio while attaching to w3wp.exe processes. Have you tried what I suggested earlier?

Comment: Try to use "this.EventFiringEnabled = false;" at the start of event & "this.EventFiringEnabled = true;" at the end of event

Comment: @christopherclark the name you see in Powershell is not "weird". This is the name declared in the element.xml file within the `<Receiver><Name></Name>` tag. It is not related to the receiver class name, it's just a -perhaps descriptive- label you assign to the event receiver

Comment: I have done the event firing enabled. I'm not sure however if the ItemField is named "Name" where can I check what the default Document Library Name is?

Also, again it is a document library, do I use a different code?

Comment: I need the Link in the Url Changed more-so. I need spaces or "%20" replaced with +. I just assumed changing "Name" would have the same effect.